# MySQL Preference Pane and login errors

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, macos, command-line

I am going through the very straightforward MySQL installation and am consistently running in to a myriad of errors.

I downloaded the MySQL community server for mac [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (the DMG file)

After installing I got the generated password for `root@localhost`.

Then I created a `.bash_profile` file in my `~/` directory and put this line in it:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

I then restarted my terminal and ran the command `mysqladmin -u root -p password`, which then asks me for my password, which I input the generated password it gave me, which then gives me the error:

`mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`

running `mysqld` gives me:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2018-01-23T20:06:55.928536Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-01-23T20:06:55.928877Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-01-23T20:06:55.928927Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 2312 ...
2018-01-23T20:06:55.932415Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/data/GBMAC0003.lower-test
2018-01-23T20:06:55.932448Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/data/GBMAC0003.lower-test
2018-01-23T20:06:55.932582Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64/data/
2018-01-23T20:06:55.932591Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-01-23T20:06:55.932602Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-01-23T20:06:55.932672Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I've tried going to the `/data/` folder and changing the permissions but then every time I run `mysqld` it keeps telling me it doesn't have other permissions for other files and folders within the directory... eventually leading me in to a rabbit hole of errors etc.

In my System Preferences, clicking on MySQL gives me the error

```
Preferences Error
Could not load MySQL preferences pane
```

I've download mysql before and it was much more straightforward but for some reason I'm having issues this time. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling with all of the same issues

I've also tried downloading SequelPro to login in to root@localhost with the generated password through the GUI and I was still getting access errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pissed because this made zero sense but I tried uninstalling and reinstalling via brew and now everything works fine...